# Incorrect count with Ext.each decrement loop

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

In a component (eg tab) where two grids are loaded simultaneously with data, I use the following function to create a global mask which will only be removed when the stores have all been loaded. It usually works well.

```
    testLoadAllStores: function(allStores, component){

        var indexStores = 0;

        setTimeout(function () {

            Ext.each(allStores, function(storeId) {
                var store = Ext.getStore(storeId);
                 if(store){
                    if(store.isLoading()){
                        indexStores++
                        console.log(indexStores);

                        store.on('load', function() {
                             indexStores--;
                             console.log(indexStores);
                            if (indexStores == 0){
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    if(component.isMasked()){
                                          component.unmask();
                                    }
                                 }, 500);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else if(!store.isLoading() && indexStores == 0){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            if(component.isMasked()){
                                  component.unmask();
                            }
                         }, 500);
                    }

                 }
            });
        }, 500);
    }
```

In the controller the function is called as follows

```
    var allStores = ['storeOne', 'storeTwo'];
    var component = Ext.getBody();
    component.mask();
    App.util.Util.testLoadAllStores(allStores, component);
```

However I am having a problem in the following situation: every time a row of the grid is selected two charts are displayed. In this case the function testLoadAllStores is called and only when the charts  stores are loaded the unmask is fired.

The problem is that every time I select a row (selectChange event) the indexStores-- gives the following values (it works but *countdown* is not correct).

```
//first selection
1
2
1
0

//second selection
1
2
-1
1
-2
0

// third selection
1
2
-3
-1
1
-4
-2
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep your old listeners, and just add new ones on top. This means that each time you load the stores, the old listeners are counting down from zero to below-zero.

To prevent cluttering your stores with listeners, potentially slowing the app down over time, you should mark the listener `single`, which will remove the listener after it is fired for the first time:

```
store.on('load', function() {
    ...
}, this, {
    single: true
});
```

Description here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Evented.html#method-on--options